# Unable to receive the meteor object inside the html

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

In my meteor project I am trying to get a meteor object and iterate it in html.

My html code is as follows:

```
<ul>
   {{#each userTerritory myObject}}
  <li class="">{{myObject.name}}</li>
   {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

Created a helper class in  client.js and I am doing a method call as follows to retrieve an object from mongo db

```
 Template.dash_board_content1.helpers({

      'userTerritory': function(){

        Meteor.call('userTerritoryList',function(error,result){
          console.log(result);
          if(!error){

            return result;

                  }else{
            alert("error : " + error);
          }

        });
      }
    });
```

method in server.js as follows:

```
in server.js

'userTerritoryList': function(){
  console.log("testing");
  return Country.find().fetch();;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a Meteor method call here instead of a publish / subscribe?

Comment: @zim Using Methods is considered the better approach regarding security. It has many times been advised to use methods and implement checks for authenticity, roles and so on.

Comment: I think you're thinking of Meteor methods vs client-side writes. pub/sub is secure, and imho fits your problem better than a method call.

Comment: You are correct, was not thinking clear enough. Pub/sub may be already the better solution here.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your suggestion. I am finding it very useful. Its working.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor methods don't work with Blaze's helpers by default, to make them work together you could use this package: [meteor-reactive-method](https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-reactive-method)

```
Template.dash_board_content1.helpers({
  userTerritory: function(){
    return ReactiveMethod.call('userTerritoryList');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: as @zim pointed out, you may rather use Meteor's publication and subscription functionality. This will be the best solution to your described problem.

Read further on:  https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html

If you still rely on using your server side call, you can use either the reactive method package, as @Khang pointed out. If you want to have more granular access about your Result Values, you should use a reactive dict:

```
import {Template} from 'meteor/templating';
import {ReactiveDict} from 'meteor/reactive-dict';

// create a new reactive dictionary to store reactive variables
// let's call it state
Template.dash_board_content1.onCreated(function onCreated(){

    //this refers to the Template.instance() here
    this.state = new ReactiveDict();

    //initial value of userTerritoryList is null
    //it will return nothing until it has been changed
    this.state.set('userTerritoryList', null);
    //you can even set an errors variable
    this.state.set('errors', []);
});
```

Then you can access the reactive dict via Template.instance():

```
Template.dash_board_content1.helpers({

    'userTerritory': function(){
        const territoryList = Template.instance().state.get('userTerritoryList');

        if (territoryList) return territoryList;

        Meteor.call('userTerritoryList', function(error,result){
            if(!error){
                Template.instance().state.set('userTerritoryList', result);
            } else {
                const errs = Template.instance().state.get('errors');
                errs.push(error);
                //update errors
                Template.instance().state.set('errors', errs);
            }
        });
    },

    'getErrors' : function() {
        //use in your template to display multiple err messages
        return  Template.instance().state.get('errors');
    },
});
```

The useTerritory helper uses the Meteor.call only if it has not been set. Still, you can easily change the method, so that it always calls the method.

Notice, that you can thereby also implement a more granular error handling.

Comment: imho helpers shouldn't be async. Better to put the method call inside an autorun() in onCreated() and let the helper return the contents of a reactive var.

Comment: You could do that, too. I prefer this approach to prevent my autorun from becoming too big. It makes it a lot easier for me to debug when all reactive variable related code is in  place.